# Elasticsearch bulk import failed when json has array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch version 6.2.3.

I have 100k json documents that each document has an array of objects.  Each object has 2 fields (oid, instance and value).

For example:

```
{"id":214,"config":{ "_id": "111", "data": [ { "oid" : "3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance" : "0", "value" : "0" }, { "oid" : "3.999.2.5.2", "instance" : "0", "value" : "my_value" } ] } }
```

I created mapping for this json as follows:

```
PUT /configuration
{
 "mappings": {
  "doc": {
   "properties": {
    "config": {"type": "text"},
    "id": {"type": "integer"}
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Then I tried to bulk insert the jsons.  However, after about 1 minute of processing I got back the prompt with no other message, but the index is empty with 0 rows.  I assume the problem is related to the fact I have an array inside my json.  How can this be solved.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/configuration/doc/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @configuration2.json
```

Thanks
Avi

Comment: `config` cannot be of type `text` since it is an `object` in your data. Replace `text` by `object` and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks! do I need to map also the array of oid, instance and value?

Comment: No you don't have to, ES will figure it out. However, if you want to define precise types for those fields, then you might. It's a good practice to do it, though.